# Remove empty attritbutes node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, null

I am trying to remove the xml node which is having empty values below my code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" >
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[.!='']" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

### Input:

```
<Test><id value=""></id><name value="Test"></name></Test>
```

### Output:

```
<Test><id /><name value="Test" /></Test>
```

### Expected Output:

```
<Test><name value="Test" /></Test>
```

Here `<id\>` tag should remove. Please suggest where am missing.
Please help me to solve the above problem.

Comment: Please be more precise about the conditions for dropping an element. For example "has at least one attribute whose value is zero length", "has at least one attribute and all attributes are zero length".

Answer (score 1):

Your script skips only such **empty attributes**, not the whole containig
element.

If you want to skip **the whole element** with at least one empty attribute,
use an empty template, matching such elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@* = '']"/>
```

and an ordinary *identity template*.

To omit empty lines, that are left in places of these "deleted" elements,
you may add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to your script.